# problems selecting next item in autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulties with this combo-box:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

I've implemented it on my site and it works great, but i get loads of complaints when people have selected something and they want to go to the next item in the combo-box.
normally you would click on the combo-box and press the down key but this does not work with this particular code.

what i'm looking for is to modify this code.

I've tried several things, such as trying to set the ui-state-focus of the drop down list to the selected item when it shows but i have not been able to get that to work properly.
I've also tried adding a scroll bar to the drop down menu and then setting the selection highlight on the item.

I've currently made a 'Hack' where i simply show the original  item and edited the code so the down triangle of that box is visible right next to the input field. So when the users clicks on it he will get the original drop down menu without being able to filter it but he can simply use key down or up to select the next or previous.
Unfortunately this is extremely dirty and i'd like to clean it up a bit

```
$.widget("custom.combobox", {
                    _create: function () {
                        this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                          .addClass("custom-combobox")
                          .insertBefore(this.element);
                        this.element.width(5).addClass("showAllButton");
                        this._createAutocomplete();
                        this._createShowAllButton();
                    },
```

Is what i'm trying possible or do i need to use a different component? if it is possible how should i go about fixing it?

I'd like to add that the filter/auto-complete option is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace `_source` method with flowing code. It will open full list of options when list was not visible before filtering starts, and that is what you need when user reenters combo and press down key. I haven't tested this solution for all cases and I know for instance that this wont select value that was previously selected but it is a start :)

If you need to enhance this further you should check out [autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) and how to extend it to suit your need.

```
this._source = function( request, response ) {
    var input = this.input;
    var wasOpened = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
        var text = $( this ).text();
        if ( this.value && ( !wasOpened || !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
                label: text,
                value: text,
                option: this
            };
    }) );
}
```